# Powershell: msiexec /X throws error 1619 when call from script

Tags: powershell, cmd, uninstallation, windows-installer

i did write a script to deinstall java from windows 7 machines:

```
[...]
$p2=start-process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/X $uninstall32 /qn REMOVE=ALL /norestart " -PassThru -wait -verb runAs
$p2.WaitForExit()
[...]
```

where is like `$uninstall32 = {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F03217065FF}`

if i call these ps1 file as an admin directly, everythin went well.
In Order of an Update Process i have to call my (working) ps1 file from a `.bat` file. these is calling my `ps1` file in this way

```
if exist "%programfiles%\java\jre7" (

    powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass"
    powershell.exe -NoProfile -file %~dp0uninstalljava7.ps1
    powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy "restricted"
)
```

then is erythin goin wrong: msiexec throws 1619 ?

I don't get it ?!

---

Solved:

a for me working solution is:

```
Set-StrictMode -Version 2

$uninstall32key = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
$uninstall64key = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

$hklm32 = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView]::Registry32)
$hklm64 = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView]::Registry64)

$key32 = $hklm32.OpenSubKey($uninstall32key)
$key64 = $hklm64.OpenSubKey($uninstall64key)

$subkeys32 = $key32.GetSubKeyNames()
$subkeys64 = $key64.GetSubKeyNames()


foreach($subkey in $subkeys32)
{
    $key = $hklm32.OpenSubKey($uninstall32key+"\\"+$subkey)
    $displayName = $key.GetValue("DisplayName")

    if ($displayName -match "Java 7")
    {
        $uninstall32 =$key.GetValue("UninstallString") 
        if ($uninstall32) {
        $uninstall32 = $uninstall32 -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
        $params = @{
            "FilePath" = "$Env:SystemRoot\system32\msiexec.exe"
            "ArgumentList" = @(
                "/x"
                $uninstall32
                "/qn"
                "REMOVE=ALL"
                "/norestart"
            )
            "Verb" = "runas"
            "PassThru" = $true
            }
            $app1 = start-process @params
            $app1.WaitForExit()
        }
    }  
}

foreach($subkey in $subkeys64)
{
    $key = $hklm64.OpenSubKey($uninstall64key+"\\"+$subkey)
    $displayName = $key.GetValue("DisplayName")

    if ($displayName -match "Java 7")
    {
        $uninstall64 =$key.GetValue("UninstallString") 
        if ($uninstall64) {
        $uninstall64 = $uninstall64 -Replace "msiexec.exe","" -Replace "/I","" -Replace "/X",""
        $params = @{
            "FilePath" = "$Env:SystemRoot\system32\msiexec.exe"
            "ArgumentList" = @(
                "/x"
                $uninstall64
                "/qn"
                "REMOVE=ALL"
                "/norestart"
            )
            "Verb" = "runas"
            "PassThru" = $true
            }
            $app1 = start-process @params
            $app1.WaitForExit()
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: that's means specific file or package does not accessible or valid for install  if you use just powershell script for test path just use `Test-path` and for run script `powershell -noexit "& ""path of script"""`

Comment: powershell -noexit "& ""path of script""" , doesnt help -> 1619

Comment: As an aside, [PowerShell.exe has an ExecutionPolicy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx) parameter for the session so you don't have to change it machine wide and then change it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
$appGUID = "{26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F03217065FF}"
$params = @{
  "FilePath" = "$Env:SystemRoot\system32\msiexec.exe"
  "ArgumentList" = @(
    "/x"
    $appGUID
    "/qn"
    "REMOVE=ALL"
    "/norestart"
  )
  "Verb" = "runas"
  "PassThru" = $true
}
$app = start-process @params
$app.WaitForExit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, the start-process parameter -ArgumentList (Alias : -arg in your example) accepts ARRAY of parameters. Passing a single string is not working properly.

Try like this :

```
$Args = @( "/X", "$uninstall32", "/qn", "REMOVE=ALL",  "/norestart" )
$p2=start-process "msiexec.exe" -argumentList $args -PassThru -wait -verb runAs
```

Also, if the dollar symbol in  "$Uninstall32" is a parameter for your installer, you should write it between simple quotes : '$uninstall32'